# Не выводятся кнопки в меню телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота на питоне, при нажатии на любую из кнопок (Профиль, Каталог товаров, Информация) бот не реагирует, хотя выводит приветствие вначале. Почему? Кнопки должны быть вида как на фото.

```
    bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
    def bot_message(message): 
    if message.chat.type == 'private': 
        if message.text == ' Информация': 
            response_text='text'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response_text, reply_markup=markup) 
        elif message.text == 'Профиль': 
            response_text='Имя: {0.first_name}/nГород: {selected_city}' 
        elif message.text == 'Каталог товаров':                      
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True) 
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Выберите город') 
            markup.add(item1) 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Каталог товаров', reply_markup=markup)
```

[![

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `bot.message_handler()` - это декоратор для функции, а не сама функция (то есть ты пропустил знак `@`), должно быть вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```